# Why don't these equations display as code formatting?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, code-formatting

In this question:

[Formatting a txt file of equations into the same format and then manipulating them for linear algebra calculations in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15983553/1730674)

The three lines from the 'txt' file with three equations is indented properly but doesn't display as code:

```
-38 y1  +  35 y2  +  31 y3  = -3047

 11 y1  + -13 y2  + -34 y3  = 784

 34 y1  + -21 y2  +  19 y3  = 2949
```

They display properly here.

Comment: That's funny.. I got them to work if I removed all the spaces and re-added them.. Or at least it worked in the preview.

Comment: Looks OK now ...

Comment: Thanks @Seth, your'e right. I tried that several times, including getting rid of the `-` at the front of the first line, dunno what was going on. Looks good though now as @mgilson says.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what can be seen from [the source](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9c0b08bd-1788-4134-9961-3be5d589aea8/view-source) (You need to view the source of the page):

```
    -38 y1 &#160;+ &#160;35 y2 &#160;+ &#160;31 y3 &#160;= -3047

 &#160;  11 y1 &#160;+ -13 y2 &#160;+ -34 y3 &#160;= 784

&#160;   34 y1 &#160;+ -21 y2 &#160;+ &#160;19 y3 &#160;= 2949
```

There are `&#160;` (0x00A0) entities, which are NO-BREAK SPACE. The implementation only consider space (ASCII 32) (and tab character, from other observation) for code block.

In the source of [revision 4](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/fdf51eed-178d-43c6-81fa-fec13a31e742/view-source):

```
    -38 y1 &#160;+ &#160;35 y2 &#160;+ &#160;31 y3 &#160;= -3047

    11 y1 &#160;+ -13 y2 &#160;+ -34 y3 &#160;= 784

    34 y1 &#160;+ -21 y2 &#160;+ &#160;19 y3 &#160;= 2949
```

Comment: I was just going to edit my answer for the same. +1

Answer (score 3):

I just edited it. What I did is just removed first four spaces from second and third line and added it again. And it looks good now. Looking at a [third revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15983553/revisions) I think there might be [a different character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) instead of space (ASCII 32).